# list, set или генератор?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Очевидно, что например для проверки наличия в коллекции выгоднее использовать set, чем list,
то есть `a in [i*i for i in range(n)]` менее оптимально нежели `a in {i*i for i in range(n)}`. Но вот насколько оптимальнее использование генератора `a in (i*i for i in range(n))`? Память экономится, а ещё? Либо я не совсем понимаю как происходит проверка наличия элемента в генераторе.

Comment: В данном случае результат с генератором будет ещё хуже, чем со списком. Чтобы проверить наличие элемента в последовательности, генератор придётся полностью _вычислить_, то есть экономии никакой не будет. Будут дополнительные вызовы к виртуальной машине для создания генератора и получения данных из него.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, разве не на первом попавшемся элементе будет остановлен запрос значений из генератора? Проверял на функции-генераторе через `yield` и после совпадения с значением `in` из генератора не запрашивались новые значения

Comment: От множества тут тоже никакой пользы, только замедление. Вот если бы множество создавалось один раз и много раз раз опрашивалось - было бы выгоднее.

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, то поиск в множестве О(1)

Comment: @gil9red а если элемент в конце?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, то быть перебору всех элементов генератора, как и с list, и с set...

Comment: Не силен в генераторах, но как прерывать с помощью yield вычисление генератора, что то вроде `if x == a yield x`?

Comment: @Serhii в предложенном автором выражении коллекция создается сразу перед проверкой, и основное время будет потрачено не на поиск а на создание коллекции, а множество создается медленнее https://ideone.com/XZNhEL

Comment: @ЭрдэниЦырендоржиев его не придется прерывать. Когда оператор `in` найдет в генераторе нужный  элемент он просто не станет запрашивать следующий, и поиск завершится

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Теоретически*, если проверка будет выполняться один раз, то лучше использовать генератор, т.к. в этом случае будет проход по последовательности только до искомого элемента (или до конца последовательности, если элемента в ней нет). Для создания `set` или `list` интерпретатору нужно будет один раз обойти весь набор элементов полностью, а потом уже по нему искать.

Если проверка будет выполняться несколько раз (например, в цикле), то лучше создать готовый `set` заранее, а потом проверять наличие элемента уже в этом `set`.

Для справки:

- Поиск по списку или генератору - это [линейный поиск](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA) (т.е. просто последовательный перебор элементов, пока не найдется нужный), время поиска пропорционально длине последовательности (`O(n)`)
- Множество в Python реализуется как [хеш-таблица](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B5%D1%88-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0), время поиска (в среднем) не зависит от количества элементов, всегда примерно одинаковое (`О(1)`). Но т.к. хеш-таблица имеет более сложную внутреннюю структуру, чем список, создание множества занимает бо́льшее время.

---

Это была теория, на практике при поиске без предварительного сохранения в переменную получаем такой результат:

[image: Без подготовки]

Видим, что поиск по списку оказался немного быстрее поиска по генератору. Скорее всего из-за того, что в генераторе для получения следующего элемента требуется больше времени, чем в списке.

---

Чтобы оценить фактическую производительность для поиска с предварительной подготовкой, пишем такую программу:

```
n = 10000000
a = (n-1)**2  # худший случай для линейного поиска

s_list = [i*i for i in range(n)]
s_set = {i*i for i in range(n)}
s_gen = (i*i for i in range(n))

def in_list():
    return a in s_list

def in_set():
    return a in s_set

def in_gen():
    return a in s_gen

print(in_list())
print(in_set())
print(in_gen())
```

Запускаем с профилировщиком:

```
python3 -m cProfile -s time test.py
```

Результат:

```
True
True
True
         10000011 function calls in 3.927 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    1.976    1.976    1.976    1.976 test.py:5(<setcomp>)
 10000000    0.768    0.000    0.768    0.000 test.py:6(<genexpr>)
        1    0.625    0.625    1.393    1.393 test.py:14(in_gen)
        1    0.489    0.489    0.489    0.489 test.py:4(<listcomp>)
        1    0.069    0.069    0.069    0.069 test.py:8(in_list)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.print}
        1    0.000    0.000    3.927    3.927 test.py:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    3.927    3.927 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 test.py:11(in_set)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

Видим, что по времени создания медленнее всего создавалось множество (`<setcomp>`), потом идет генератор (`<genexpr>`), потом список (`<listcomp>`).

По времени поиска: медленнее всего - поиск по генератору (`in_gen`), чуть быстрее - по списку (`in_list`), быстрее всего - поиск в множестве (`in_set`).

Интерпретатор:

```
Python 3.6.8 (default, Aug 20 2019, 17:12:48) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
```

### Итог:

- При поиске без предварительного сохранения в переменную лучше
  использовать список. Однако, если есть ограничение по занимаемой памяти, лучше использовать генератор.
- При поиске с предварительным сохранением лучше
  использовать множество

Comment: Можно добавить, что поиск по сету О(1) =)